# How to delete a Firebase user from Android App?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to code a *Delete User* method in my Android App, but I have some issues each time I execute it. This method will be executed when a user pushes the *Delete account* button on an Activity. My apps works with FirebaseUI Auth.

Here is the method:

```java
private void deleteAccount() {
    Log.d(TAG, "ingreso a deleteAccount");
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    currentUser.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG,"OK! Works fine!");
                startActivity(new Intent(Main3WelcomeActivity.this, Main3Activity.class));
                finish();
            } 
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Ocurrio un error durante la eliminación del usuario", e);
        }
    });
}
```

1) When I execute that function a Smart Lock message appears on the screen and the user is signed in again. Here is a screenshot of this message.

[image: Smartlock message]

2) On other occasions, when the user is logged in for a long time, the function throws an Exception like this:

```
06-30 00:01:26.672 11152-11152/com.devpicon.android.firebasesamples E/Main3WelcomeActivity: Ocurrio un error durante la eliminación del usuario
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN ]
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacq.zzbN(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacn$zzg.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacy.zzbO(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzacy$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzact$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

I've read that [I have to re-authenticate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) the user but I'm not sure how to do this when I'm working with Google Sign In.

Comment: use removeUser({credentials}) to it

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As per the `Firebase`  documentation can user `delete()` method to remove user from the **Firebase**

Before remove the user please **reAuthenticate** the user.

> Sample code

```
     final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        // Get auth credentials from the user for re-authentication. The example below shows
        // email and password credentials but there are multiple possible providers,
        // such as GoogleAuthProvider or FacebookAuthProvider.
        AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
                .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234");

        // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
        user.reauthenticate(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
           user.delete()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "User account deleted.");
                    }
                }
            });

   }
});
```

For more details : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user

If you want to user re Authentication with other singin provider only need to change the `Provider` for `GoogleAuthProvider` below is the sample code

```
GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleIdToken,null);
```

Comment: Sure, but I don't know how to do the same with GoogleSignInProvider.

Comment: you have to fallow the same steps   AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleIdToken,null);  and all other steps are same

Comment: But, how can I know the user's password. Is there any method for that?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users this link may useful

Comment: Thanks sir. But I wanna ask you one more question. This code you showed us, can delete a Facebook user too?

Comment: this will delete user from firebase DB, if Facebook user authentication data in firebase then it might delete I haven't tried but if we consider general behavior this might get deleted

Comment: Okay, this is so weird, how can I know user's password?

Comment: Is it possible to delete other users from one user? as you are using `currentUser` object for Currently Logged-in user only.

Comment: @PratikButani no it is not possible.

Comment: If `currentUser` is not null then you don't need to re-authenticate

Answer (score 6):

The answer provided by Ansuita Jr. is very beautifully explained and is correct with just a small problem.
**The user gets deleted even without having successful re-authentication.** 
This is because we use

> user.delete()

in the onComplete() method which is always executed.
Therefore, we need to add an if check to check whether the task is successful or not which is mentioned below

```
user.reauthenticate(credential)
          .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
             @Override
             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "onComplete: authentication complete");
                    user.delete()
                    .addOnCompleteListener (new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.e("TAG", "User account deleted.");
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("TAG", "User account deletion unsucessful.");
                                }
                          }
                     });
                 } else {
                     Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, "Authentication failed", 
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
              }
         });
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `delete` callback already handles the case of a failure, why do you add `addOnFailureListener` later?

Try to delete it, this way:

```
private void deleteAccount() {
    Log.d(TAG, "ingreso a deleteAccount");
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    currentUser.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG,"OK! Works fine!");
                startActivity(new Intent(Main3WelcomeActivity.this, Main3Activity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG,"Something is wrong!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to store the auth token or the password at the moment your user is logging in. If your app doesn't provide such as Google Sign-in, Facebook Sign-in or others, you just need to store the password.

```
//If there's any, delete all stored content from this user on Real Time Database. 
yourDatabaseReferenceNode.removeValue();

//Getting the user instance.
final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if (user != null) {
    //You need to get here the token you saved at logging-in time.
    String token = "userSavedToken";
    //You need to get here the password you saved at logging-in time.
    String password = "userSavedPassword";

    AuthCredential credential;

    //This means you didn't have the token because user used like Facebook Sign-in method.
    if (token == null) {
       credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(user.getEmail(), password);
    } else {
       //Doesn't matter if it was Facebook Sign-in or others. It will always work using GoogleAuthProvider for whatever the provider.
       credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(token, null);
    }

    //We have to reauthenticate user because we don't know how long 
    //it was the sign-in. Calling reauthenticate, will update the 
    //user login and prevent FirebaseException (CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN) on user.delete()
    user.reauthenticate(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        //Calling delete to remove the user and wait for a result.
                        user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    //Ok, user remove
                                } else {
                                    //Handle the exception
                                    task.getException();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });    
}
```

Comment: Sir, I want to delete who authenticated right now. I mean user logged in my app and decide to delete his/her account. How I can do that?

Comment: Great answer and comment explanation for multi-provider authentication.

Comment: @Vansuita Jr. this works but when i reauthenticate then its work with invalid password also that should not the case

Answer (score 1):

@Android developers:

I faced an issue where the Firebase Auth information was persisting in the device's disk AFTER uninstalling the app. After experimenting and reading about it, I found that setting `android:allowBackup="false"` and `android:fullBackupContent="false"` in the Manifest's `<application>` tag will ensure the identity information is not persisted after the app is uninstalled.

Please note, this kind of persistence was not happening on all Android devices. In fact, it started happening on one of my devices that never had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the sign-in method is "Anonymous", you can just call

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().delete().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                       if (task.isSuccessful()){
                           Log.d(TAG, "Deletion Success");
                       }
                    });
```

But if it's a different method, you will need a re-authentication.
[How to re-authenticate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user)

Answer (score 0):

Use this methods :-

**remove()**

is equivalent to calling `set(null)`.

or

**removeUser()**

```
removeUser(credentials, [onComplete])
```

Answer (score 0):

Only get current user and delete it by using following method it'll work fine

```
user.delete();
```

and you can add on Oncompletelistner also
by addind`user.delete().addOnCompleteListner(new OnCompleteListner)`and more on

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **AuthUI** or **FirebaseAuth** you can just do the following

```
 AuthUI.getInstance().delete(context).addOnSuccessListener {
           
 }.addOnFailureListener{

 }
```

OR

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.delete().addOnSuccessListener...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FirebaseUI Auth you can just do the following

```
private void delete() {
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    user.delete()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        startActivity(new Intent(Main3WelcomeActivity.this, Main3Activity.class));
                        finish();
                        Toast.makeText(Main3WelcomeActivity.this,"Account deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(Home.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }
            });}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).