# How to remove user authentication and user account in Realtime database at the same time?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to create a function where user can remove their own account. If the user removes their account. All their information will be deleted and user authentication also will be removed. I have created the function but somehow at the Firebase authentication the user email did not get deleted.

[image]

The picture above shows the account has been deleted but inside the authentication the account still not gets deleted.

[image]

```
 delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustProfileActivity.this);
                    dialog.setTitle("Are you sure?");
                    dialog.setMessage("Deleting this account will result in completely removing your " +
                            " account from the system and you won't be able to access the app.");
                    dialog.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            progBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Customer").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                            currentUser.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                        progBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
```

I want to achieve a result where user account will get deleted including their data inside the firebase authentication.

Comment: Do you have any errors? Please log into the console `task.getException().getMessage()` if the task is not successful. What are your security rules? Please add them to your question.

Comment: the account got deleted from firebase realtime database but not from the authentication

Comment: Please answer the question from the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't know deep dive firebase. But I think, you can use this method:

Create a cloud function. This function will do, 
when you delete user on Realtime Database, function is triggering for delete user on Authentication.

You can do you want using the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions

Answer (score 0):

Deleting data from Realtime Database will not also delete an account registered with Firebase Authentication.  If you want the user to be able to [delete their own account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user), you will have to call [FirebaseUser.delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#delete()) as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user).

See also: [How to delete a Firebase user from Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114689/how-to-delete-a-firebase-user-from-android-app)