# How can I delete user's account from Firebase REST API?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

From the documentation of the Firebase **REST API**, to **log in** the user with **email and password**, just need to follow [this step](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password):

```
@override
  Future<UserModel> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    String email,
    String password,
  ) async {
    final authModel = AuthModel(email: email, password: password);
    final response = await post(
      https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=YOUR_API_KEY,
      body: jsonEncode(authModel.toJson()),
    ).timeout(const Duration(seconds: AppConstants.TIMEOUT));
    if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
      final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return UserModel(
        displayName: body["displayName"],
        email: body["email"],
        uid: body["localId"],
        refreshToken: body["refreshToken"],
        idToken: body["idToken"],
      );
    } else {
      throw Exception(jsonDecode(response.body)["error"]["message"]);
    }
  }
```

The **AuthModel**:

```
class AuthModel {
  String email, password;
  bool returnSecureToken = true;

  AuthModel({this.email, this.password});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> json = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    json["email"] = this.email;
    json["password"] = this.password;
    json["returnSecureToken"] = this.returnSecureToken;
    return json;
  }
}
```

So, the login is working fine. And then, to relogin (reauthenticate) user everytime he open the app again, you just need to use the refreshToken saved from the last login, following [this step](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-refresh-token):

```
@override
  Future<UserModel> renewToken(String refreshToken) async {
    ExchangeTokenModel exchangeToken = ExchangeTokenModel(
      refreshToken: refreshToken,
    );
    final response = await post(
      https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=YOUR _API_KEY,
      body: jsonEncode(exchangeToken.toJson()),
    ).timeout(const Duration(seconds: AppConstants.TIMEOUT));
    final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return UserModel(
      uid: body["user_id"],
      idToken: body["id_token"],
      refreshToken: body["refresh_token"],
    );
  }
```

The **ExchangeTokenModel**:

```
class ExchangeTokenModel {
  final String grantType = "refresh_token";
  String refreshToken;

  ExchangeTokenModel({this.refreshToken});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> json = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    json["grant_type"] = grantType;
    json["refresh_token"] = refreshToken;
    return json;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "ExchangeTokenModel"
        "["
        "grant_type: $grantType, "
        "refresh_token: $refreshToken"
        "]";
  }
}
```

So, at this point, everything is working fine. The problem is to **delete** user's account using the **REST API**.
From the documentation, [this step](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-delete-account) **don't** say this current error while trying to delete an user account:

> {error: {code: 400, message: CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN, errors: [{message: CREDENTIAL_TOO_OLD_LOGIN_AGAIN, domain: global, reason: invalid}]}}

The only two *Common error codes* are: **INVALID_ID_TOKEN** and **USER_NOT_FOUND**.

Searching on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114689/how-to-delete-a-firebase-user-from-android-app) from stackoverflow, I found that, for security, the user should relogin again.

So, how can I solve it (not telling user to sign out and sign in again)? Because everytime when user open the app, I already reauthenticate user's idToken credential from the ExchangeToken step.
Everytime user's have a **VALID** idToken to read/write on db, but he **CAN'T** delete his account due to this error. The documentation don't specify this error and **don't** have an enpoint to reauthenticate the user? Is that correct or it's a bug on firebase auth?

Ps.1: this error only appears if you already logged in for more than 30min/1h (don't matter if you open the app again to renew the idToken, the error persists)

Ps.2: if you sign out and sign in again, the request is successful completed